# Identifying replacement bearings for installed heater fan motor

Tags: ball-bearing, motor

**TLDR:** Trying to identify the right kind of replacement ball bearing. Usually they have a standard code # which can be supplied by different manufacturers. But the ones I need don't seem to fit that system.

---

We have a number of fan heaters, some of which are making noise (others are dead quiet). These are a hot-water type which are installed in walls or in the "kickspace" under cabinets, and the fan blows air over the HW coil.

Upon inspection it is the rotating fan / motor assembly that is producing the noise, and that whole assembly can be removed for service / replacement. I've exposed the bearings which are noisy, but am having trouble identifying a replacement.

The bearing is stamped **`BB1023`** but this doesn't seem like a standard bearing code. **Does anyone know how to interpret this number and/or is there an equivalent standard code?**

Ideally someone may know of a canonical reference to bearing codes. *I have found references which purport to be such a thing, but don't include this numbering.*

(If not I will probably just measure the originals with a caliper & try to find the best match that way; this just seems more likely to go wrong because not only the obvious dimensions are important.)

---

Notes:

- The few bearings I can find online with that code are much more $$ than I would normally expect, so either these really are specialized and nonstandard or they are just hard to find with that nomenclature.
- In a few cases the `BB1023` code seems to be cross-referenced with `627N1Z` and other codes ... but I am somewhat mistrustful of the correctness of random product information. And `627N1Z` seems to be an oddball code also when I've tried to find it in catalogs.
- The heaters happen to be common Beacon-Morris models, and entire replacement fans are available but at a much greater cost than what I'd expect just the bearings to be.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to find different bearings is by the size bb1023 crosses to a double sealed 6.35 x22 x7  mm bearing 
Mr627zz is the same id/od and 1/4” thick so it is slightly thicker and may work under 5 bucks. Looking at the bearing specs I would give it a try. I cross bearings for motors all the time, I can tell you a timkin or sky bearing in some cases is worth the extra but in a light duty motor like a fan I would save a few $ 
Mr627-2rs
Mr627zz 
I thought I typed in the wrong size after double checking my answer but I just typed the size wrong in the answer corrected.

Comment: What did you use to find the size of a bearing stamped with BB1023?  Is there some standard table somewhere that lists this?

Comment: I found Timken or SKF bearings matched any sizes I was looking for... usually went to a bearing specialist though - either with the numbers or caliper measurements...

Comment: The BB might stand for Berry Bearing. I used to get bearing from them when I was a mechanic at a steal heat treating co. All their numbers were BB ????..  They've been out of business for like 15 years...

Comment: @Jphil1619 , I used a Mcguire cross reference book , they provide them every so often as my company purchases a large number of bearings, 
Mcguire is a local distributor first you look up the bearing the listing provides the size and the part numbers they carry. I think they might have a cross on their site but I use the book , guess I am old school.

Comment: Yup, MR627-ZZ/.250 was a perfect replacement. I got these from Amazon and the supplier was "Boca Bearing". So maybe that's the origin of the BB in the number.  https://www.bocabearings.com/products/mr627-zzc--250-ps2-669